# Why aren't the middle elements getting sorted?

Tags: c, sorting

I'm implementing a sorting algorithm for fun, but for reasons I don't know, what I've implemented so far doesn't sort the middle. Here are the steps of the algorithm:

1. Get the indices of the minimum and maximum values
2. Move the minimum value to the minimum index, the maximum value to the maximum index
3. Increment the minimum index and decrement the maximum index
4. Repeat from 1. while the minimum index is less than the maximum index

I know this isn't the most efficient sorting algorithm, but it's just for fun. Here is the code

```
#define ui64 uint64_t

void print(ui64* array, ui64 ArraySize);

ui64 random(void) 
{
  ui64 r = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) r = r*2 + rand()%2;
  return r;
}

void generate(ui64* array, ui64 ArraySize);

Pair getMinMaxIndices(ui64* array, ui64 minIndex, ui64 maxIndex)
{
    Pair minmax, minmaxIndices;
    
    if(maxIndex == 0)
    {
        minmax.max = array[0];
        minmax.min = array[0];
        
        minmaxIndices.max = 0;
        minmaxIndices.min = 0;
        
        return minmaxIndices;
    }
    
    if(array[minIndex] > array[minIndex + 1])
    {
        minmax.max = array[minIndex];
        minmax.min = array[minIndex + 1];
        
        minmaxIndices.max = minIndex;
        minmaxIndices.min = minIndex + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        minmax.max = array[minIndex + 1];
        minmax.min = array[minIndex];
        
        minmaxIndices.max = minIndex + 1;
        minmaxIndices.min = minIndex;
    }

    for(int i = minIndex + 2; i < maxIndex + 1; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > minmax.max)
        {
            minmax.max = array[i];
            minmaxIndices.max = i;
        }

        else if(array[i] < minmax.min)
        {
            minmax.min = array[i];
            minmaxIndices.min = i;
        }
    }

    return minmaxIndices;
}

void swap(ui64* array, ui64 index1, ui64 index2);

void closingCurtainsSort(ui64* array, ui64 ArraySize)
{
    Pair minmaxIndices, indexLimits;
    
    indexLimits.min = 0;
    indexLimits.max = ArraySize - 1;
    
    while(indexLimits.min < indexLimits.max)
    {
        minmaxIndices = getMinMaxIndices(array, indexLimits.min, indexLimits.max);
        
        swap(array, minmaxIndices.min, indexLimits.min);
        swap(array, minmaxIndices.max, indexLimits.max);
        
        indexLimits.min++;
        indexLimits.max--;
    }
}
```

Here is the step by step as generated by the program for this hardcoded array: array2[10] = {0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9}

```
Array2
0
2
4
6
8
1
3
5
7
9
Current minimum value -> array[0]: 0
Current maximum value -> array[9]: 9
Current minimum index -> 0
Current maximum index -> 9

Loop 1
0
2
4
6
8
1
3
5
7
9
Current minimum value -> array[0]: 0
Current maximum value -> array[9]: 9
Current minimum index -> 1
Current maximum index -> 8

Loop 2
0
1
4
6
7
2
3
5
8
9
Current minimum value -> array[5]: 2
Current maximum value -> array[4]: 7
Current minimum index -> 2
Current maximum index -> 7

Loop 3
0
1
2
6
5
4
3
7
8
9
Current minimum value -> array[5]: 4
Current maximum value -> array[4]: 5
Current minimum index -> 3
Current maximum index -> 6

Loop 4
0
1
2
6
5
4
3
7
8
9
Current minimum value -> array[6]: 3
Current maximum value -> array[3]: 6
Current minimum index -> 4
Current maximum index -> 5

Loop 5
0
1
2
6
5
4
3
7
8
9
Current minimum value -> array[5]: 4
Current maximum value -> array[4]: 5
Current minimum index -> 5
Current maximum index -> 4
```

EDIT:
Removed the following:

- included headers
- documentation
- debugging function
- main()

Declared functions with obvious implementation instead of defining

Comment: There's too much code here. Please post a [mcve] that's only related to the question.

Comment: So step through it in a debugger until you identify a case where you think it _should_ swap two elements and doesn't. Then think about why.

Comment: Function `getMinMaxIndices` seems unnecessarily convoluted, possibly giving scope for error. Why not simplify it to one simple loop, with the initial values and indices obtained from the first element in the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can (and does) double-swap erroneously.

Example: after three iterations your sequence will generate like this:

```
Loop 1 : 0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9 
Loop 2 : 0 1 4 6 7 2 3 5 8 9 
Loop 3 : 0 1 2 6 5 4 3 7 8 9
```

Now we're moving to the partition [3,6]. Within this partition we discover that the 'minval' index is 6, and the 'maxval' index is 3. I.e. the extreme values need to be swapped with each other, as each is sitting in the other's target location. However, your algorithm does this:

```
swap(array, minmaxIndices.min, indexLimits.min);
swap(array, minmaxIndices.max, indexLimits.max);
```

Therefore, you swap them into the correct position, then swap them right back.

When the targets of the landing spots (the outer edges of the current partition) are, in fact, the source(s) of the data being swapped for the opposite extreme value, you should only swap *once*.

```
swap(array, minmaxIndices.min, indexLimits.min);
if (indexLimits.min != minmaxIndices.max)
    swap(array, minmaxIndices.max, indexLimits.max);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I needed. One thing I noticed is that the error only happens if there's an even number of elements.